# How to use vlookup function in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Sir, 
I am having a material item example:" Tupperware bottle"
 With value 100. 
But I want to write only "Tupper" and get the value using  vlookup  function.
Note: I do not want to write the whole word "Tupperware bottle. 
Please tell me how to use vlookup function for this.

Comment: There is expected to show some own effort. Like to explicitly mention what you tried And what failed.

Comment: Use `VLOOKUP()` in the normal way, then extract the substring you want using `LEFT()`, as in `LEFT(VLOOKUP(...),6)`.

Comment: To expand on what AFH said.. you can also use a `CONTAINS()` function as well depending on how you wish to do it

Comment: Maybe better to use excel table and then use the filter function. You can type in partial keywords, and it will pull up all matches, as there may be other Tupperware items.

Comment: Can you display the vlookup formula you are currently using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the VLOOKUP function with the addition of the "*"(WILDCARD), this will allow you to use VLOOKUP without typing out the full search criteria

e.g  =VLOOKUP(lookupval&"*",range,column,false or 0)

In addition, the VLOOKUP with "*"(WILDCARD) will only work with exact match mode (false/0)

Comment: I would use the VLOOKUP function with the addition of the "*"(WILDCARD), this will allow you to use VLOOKUP without typing out the full search criteria

e.g =VLOOKUP(lookupval&"*",range,column,false or 0)

In addition, the VLOOKUP with "*"(WILDCARD) will only work with exact match mode (false/0)

Comment: Sir, this was useful but when I am using for the another word it is displaying "#N/A"

Comment: I would use the VLOOKUP function with the addition of the "*"(WILDCARD), this will allow you to use VLOOKUP without typing out the full search criteria

e.g =VLOOKUP(lookupval&"*",range,column,false or 0)

In addition, the VLOOKUP with "*"(WILDCARD) will only work with exact match mode (false/0)

Comment: I would wrap the VLOOKUP function in a IFERROR function, that way you can decide what to show if there is an error

e.g.
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(lookupval&"*",range,column,false or 0),"Choosen Message")

Comment: What is the "choosen message" here

Comment: What you want EXCEL to display if there is an error with the function, or if the function doesn't find the word in the VLOOKUP, rather than having "N/A" like you stated earlier, you could have "Item not found", or something along those lines

Comment: Actually, bro in excel sheet I am having material item with codes like eg: bottle -6000186, cups - 6000135 .......like many items with its code. What I need is, I used to prepare the bills in another excel sheet for that I will copy that item with and to paste in the desired sheet, which it take more time for that.

Comment: What I want is, in that desired sheet in which I am preparing a bill, when ever I type the material it should extracts the code.

Comment: Plz help to sort this,  half I got from u.

Comment: Help to solve that #n/a error.

Comment: Can you attach a quick screenshot, to help me better understand?

Comment: Here there is no option for attachment.

Comment: Thanks elbow I almost got help from your given vlookup function thanks once again

Comment: Plz tell why this #n/a error occurs.

Comment: #N/A is an error value result of the VLO0KUP function, if it cannot find the value. 
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(...),AlternativeExpression,VLOOKUP(.....)) allows you to replace the error code by the value of your choice, e.g. "Not Found" or   0 or whatever.

Comment: Sorry, only
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(...),AlternativeExpression)

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested VLOOKUP.

The inner one looking for Tupper and returning Tupperware bottle.

```
=VLOOKUP("Tupper",AbbrevTable, 2,false)
```

would return "Tupperware bottle".

It is reusable with list of more of your abbreviation.

```
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP("Tupper",AbbrevTable, 2,false),ItemTable,2,false)
```

would return 100, or whatever it is to return.

I am supposing both tables have 2 columns.

Or, use just the cell address where your  abbr. is, like

```
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(A2,AbbrevTable, 2,false),ItemTable,2,false)
```

Comment: Sir, what is abbrev table and item table here.

Comment: They care placeholders for addressing your real item table a auxiliary translation table abbreviation versus full text.

Comment: I think column_table is the abbrev table

Comment: The ItemTable is the placeholder for the table, where is the item list, like "Tuppleware bottle", 100. Or, it can be a real name of that table, if you name the table.
the AbbrevTable is an auxiliary table you would create, where in the left column would be the abbreviation like "Tupper", in the right column would be the full item names like "Tupperware bottle", returned by the inner vlookup )

Comment: But the above answer with "Tupper"&"*" works well